# Google Analytics Reporting API Credentials

Tags: api, email, analytics, reporting, credentials

I'm new to Google Analytics API.

At some point, I'm supposed to allow the API to access the Analytics account I am interested in to an address like :

quickstart@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com

I assumed :

- quickstart should be replaced by the name of my project
- PROJECT-ID by the 6-digits number appearing in the URL of my project's developer console interface

However, I haven't seen this address (or such) plainly written anywhere, and Analytics says this address doesn't exist, so that I just can't add it.

Did I miss something here ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

The email syntax is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts).
Though, I had to create this service account, from the Google API admin panel > project parameters > Service Account view, with reading rights.